# Android Firebase: Phone Authentication Custom Country Code

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My code for Firebase authentication by phone is:

```
startActivityForResult(
    AuthUI.getInstance()
    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
    .setAvailableProviders(
        Collections.singletonList(newAuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.PHONE_VERIFICATION_PROVIDER).build()))
    .build(), RC_SIGN_IN);
```

The result is 
[image: Firebase auth. by phone]

By default the country code is `1 (USA)`.

Do I need to set another country code by default (e.g. `244`). How I can do this?

Comment: It looks like the default country code is currently hardcoded to US. I've submitted a [feature request](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/916) to change this

Answer (score 2):

With the lastest(I am using 4.3.1) version of the libary you can directly set the default paramters while building the IdpConfig Object

```
AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder()
                            .setDefaultCountryIso("IN")
                            .build()

Example input: {'+52', 'us'}
```

PS: I am not sure when it was first added to the library

Answer (score 0):

```
 Bundle params = new Bundle();
 params.putString(EXTRA_DEFAULT_COUNTRY_CODE, "AO");

 IdpConfig phoneConfigWithDefaultNumber =
          new IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.PHONE_VERIFICATION_PROVIDER)
                  .setParams(params)
                  .build();
```

Refer to this [link](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/pull/919/files/d9591d6d66def7419bae265faf93bbd1f41f43f3#diff-46b10a690795758a8db6b0f86c9afddc)

Answer (score -1):

```
public class CountryData {
    public static final String[] countryNames = {"Afghanistan", "Albania",
            "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Antartica", "Argentina", "Armenia",
            "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahrain", "Banglades", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize",
            "Benin", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia And Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei Darussalam",
            "Bulgaria", "Brukina Faso", "Myanmar", "Brundi", "Combodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde",
            "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Chrismas Island", "Cocos(Keeling) Islands",
            "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Crotia",
            "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibuti", "Timor-leste", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador",
            "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Falkland Island (malvinas)", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji",
            "Finland", "France", "French Polynesia", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar",
            "Greece", "Greenland", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-bissau", "Guyan", "Haiti",
            "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Isle of Man", "Israel", "Italy",
            "Ivory Coast", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", "KazaKhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Kuwait",
            "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg",
            "macao", "Macedonia", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands", "Mauritania",
            "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Morocco",
            "Mozambique", "Nambia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherland", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicargua", "Niger", "Nigeria",
            "Niue", "Korea", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines",
            "Pitcairn", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Romania", "Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Saint Barthelemy", "Samoa",
            "San Marino", "Sao Tome And Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Island",
            "Somalia", "South Africa", "Korea", "Republic of", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Saint Helen", "Saint Pierre And Miquelon", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland",
            "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan",
            "Tuvalu", "United Arab Emirates", "Uganda", "United Kingdom", "Ukraine", "Uruguay", "United States", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Holy See (Vatican City State)",
            "Venezuela", "Viet Nam", "Wallis And Futuna", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"};

    public static final String[] countryAreaCodes = {"93", "355", "213", "376", "244", "672", "54", "374", "297", "61", "43",
            "994", "973", "880", "375", "32", "501", "229", "975", "591", "387", "267", "55", "673", "359", "226", "95", "257", "855",
            "237", "55", "673", "359", "226", "95", "257", "855", "237", "1", "238", "236", "235", "56", "86", "61", "61",
            "57", "269", "242", "682", "506", "385", "53", "357", "420", "45", "253", "670", "593", "20", "503", "240", "291", "372", "251", "500",
            "298", "679", "358", "33", "689", "241", "220", "995", "49", "233", "350", "30", "299", "502", "224", "245", "592", "509", "504",
            "852", "36", "91", "62", "98", "964", "353", "44", "972", "39", "225", "1876", "81", "962", "7", "254", "686", "965", "996",
            "856", "371", "961", "266", "231", "218", "423", "370", "352", "853", "389", "261", "265", "60", "960", "223", "356", "692", "222",
            "230", "262", "52", "691", "373", "377", "976", "382", "212", "258", "264", "674", "977", "31", "687", "64", "505", "227", "234", "683", "850", "47",
            "968", "92", "680", "507", "675", "595", "51", "63", "870", "48", "351", "1", "974", "40", "7", "250", "590", "685", "378", "239", "966",
            "221", "381", "248", "232", "65", "421", "386", "677", "252", "27", "82", "34", "94", "290", "508", "249", "597", "268", "46", "41", "963", "886", "992",
            "255", "66", "228", "690", "676", "216", "90", "993", "688", "971", "256", "44", "380", "598", "1", "998", "678", "39", "58", "681", "967", "260", "263"};
}
```